# Is there any language for which $\overline{L^*}=\big(\overline L\big)^*$?

Tags: formal-languages

This question was asked in peter linz exercise. I have tried languages such as $\phi,\epsilon,\Sigma^*$.

Comment: We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, thanks for Ariel's correction, since for every $L$ it holds that $\epsilon \not\in \overline{(L^*)}$  and $\epsilon \in (\overline{L})^*$ and therefore $ \overline{(L^*)}\neq (\overline{L})^*$

Comment: The empty word $\epsilon$ is in ${\overline{L}}^*$ but not in $\overline{L^*}$.

Comment: Unfortunately, this cannot be fixed, $\overline{L}^*\neq \overline{L^*}$ for every $L$ since the left hand side contains $\epsilon$ and the right doesn't.

Comment: OOPS, I needed a recap for the kleene star, you are right